# using multiple values HttpStatus in @ResponseStatus

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc

I am using the Spring annotation `@ResponseStatus` in my Exception like

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
public class UnauthorizedException extends Exception{
}
```

Problem is I want to throw the same error for a number of values like `HttpStatus.SC_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE`, etc..

Is there any way to use multiple values in `@ResponseStatus`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You can't have multiple http status codes. Check [http spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1)

If you actually want to set different status codes in different scenarios (but only one status code per response), then remove the annotation, and add it via code:

```
public X method(HttpServletResponse response) {
    if (..) {
         response.setStatus(..);
    } else {
         response.setStatus(..);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I know that we cannot have multiple http status codes in annotation but is there any workaround..

Comment: @parbi http does not allow it

Answer (score 3):

The only workaround that comes to mind is not using the `@ResponseStatus` annotation.  Consider writing your own error handling code in the controller that catches the relevant exception sets the error code in the way you would prefer for that class.  If it's in several controllers, consider writing an interceptor or using AOP.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the response code in the `HttpServletResponse` class with the `.setStatus()` method, that you could get from the `applicationContext`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create multiple exception classes and throw the appropriate one?